# Show that any set of $16$ positive integers (not all distinct) summing to $30$ has a subset summing to $n$, for $n= 1,2,\ldots,29$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Show that any set of $16$ positive integers (not all distinct) summing to $30$ has a subset summing to $n$, for $n= 1,2,\ldots,29$

I have tried it by separately considering $n$ to be $1,2,\ldots,29$. But the process is becoming large and complicated. Any smart or elegant process/suggestion is welcome.

Comment: If you could show it for $1,2,\ldots, 14,15$ then $16,\ldots , 28,29$ are easy

Comment: The use of "set" in title any question is contradicted by what you want, as sets cannot have some of their elements be equal. You might say "list" or "multiset", which would do (equally) well for the current purpose. Of course you also need to replace "subset" appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let the set of numbers be $a_i$. Arrange them in increasing order.

For a given set, let there be $k$ 1's. So $1 = a_1 = \ldots = a_k < a_{k+1}$.

**Hint:** Show that $a_{16} = \max\{\,a_i\mid i=1,\ldots,16\,\}  \leq k$.

**Hint:** Consider $T_j = \sum_{i=k+1} ^j a_i $.
To get a sum of $n$, find $ T_j \leq n < T_{j+1}$.
Instead of using $a_{j+1}$, just use the necessary number of 1's. Hence we are done.

Comment: Your proof can be used to show this generalized version.  If $n$ is a positive integer, then it is always guaranteed that  for positive integers $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k$ such that $t_1+t_2+\ldots+t_k=2n$, for each $l=1,2,\ldots,2n$, there exist $1\le i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_j\le k$ such that $t_{i_1}+t_{i_2}+\ldots+t_{i_j}=l$ if and only if $k\geq n+1$.

Comment: Yup, this is a common enough problem that I remember these 2 steps as the way to prove it.